# Check String of characters is a valid date or not

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table with field sourcefilename which has 5 records. Following are the records.

```
SN. SOURCEFILENAME
1. 20170215095453_1.Iredell Memorial Hospital Dental Eligibility.xls_INFREPT01.txt
2. Iredell Memorial Hospital Eligibility April 2017.xls_INFREPT01.txt
3. Iredell Memorial Hospital Eligibility March 2017.xls_INFREPT01.txt
4. Iredell Memorial Hospital Eligibility May 2017.xls_INFREPT01.txt
5. Iredell Memorial Hospital October 2016 Dental Eligibility.xls_EligData.txt
```

I just need to extract first 8 characters and check if its a valid date. If it is a valid date then return TRUE else FALSE.

I tried ISDATE function. Is there are any other alternatives?

```
SELECT DISTINCT SubStr(sourcefilename,1,8),
CASE WHEN isdate(SubStr(sourcefilename,1,8),'YYYYMMDD') = 1 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END  FROM ai_4451_1_metl;
```

Comment: @user7294900 : If TO_DATE is used. What value to compare??
SELECT DISTINCT SubStr(sourcefilename,1,8),
      CASE WHEN to_Date(SubStr(sourcefilename,1,8),'YYYYMMDD') = ????????
      THEN 'TRUE'
      ELSE 'FALSE' END  
 FROM ai_4451_1_metl;

Answer (score 7):

Oracle 12.2 provides a new function [VALIDATE_CONVERSION](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/VALIDATE_CONVERSION.htm#SQLRF-GUID-DC485EEB-CB6D-42EF-97AA-4487884CB2CD). So far I never used it, but I assume it would be like this:

```
CASE VALIDATE_CONVERSION(SubStr(sourcefilename,1,8) AS DATE, 'YYYYMMDD') 
   WHEN 1 THEN 'TRUE'
   ELSE 'FALSE'
END
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have Oracle 12.2 you can use the [`validate_conversion`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/VALIDATE_CONVERSION.htm) function:

```
with demo as
     ( select '20170101' as sourcetest from dual union all
       select '20171100' from dual )
select sourcetest
     , validate_conversion(sourcetest as date, 'YYYYMMDD') as test_result
from   demo;

SOURCETEST  TEST_RESULT
----------- -----------
20170101              1
20171100              0
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no Oracle built_in `isdate()` or differently named equivalent (in versions before 12cR2). But you can write your own:

```
create or replace function isdate
   ( p_date_str in varchar2 
     , p_date_fmt in varchar2 )
   return varchar2
is
    return_value varchar2(5);
    l_date date;
begin
    begin
        l_date := to_date(p_date_str, p_date_fmt);
        return_value := 'TRUE';
    exception
        when others then
            return_value := 'FALSE';
    end;
    return return_value;
end isdate;
/
```

If casting the string to a DATE datatype succeeds it's a valid date, otherwise it isn't.

If your data quality issues are such that your strings have multiple date formats then you can implement this alternate solution.

```
create or replace function isdate
   ( p_date_str in varchar2  )
   return varchar2
is
    return_value varchar2(5) := 'FALSE';
    l_date date;
    l_date_fmts sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll := sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll (
         'DD-MON-YYYY'
         , 'YYYY-MM-DD'
         , 'DD-MM-YY'
            -- etc
         );

begin
    for idx in 1..l_date_fmts.count() loop
        begin
            l_date := to_date(p_date_str, l_date_fmts)idx) );
            return_value := 'TRUE';
            exit;
        exception
            when others then
                null;
        end;
    end loop;
    return return_value;
end isdate;
/
```