# CONVERT NUMBER(10) FIELD IN ORACLE SQL TO DATE

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table where the date field is stored as a number (20161231 = 12/31/2016). I would like to convert this field to a date. I have tried the following, but have received error messages.

```
,TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TR.CHEMO_DATE, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'mm/dd/yyyy') AS CHEM_DATE
```

Error:  ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month

I have tried several things to no avail. Thanks for your assistance

Comment: Never, ever, ever store dates as numbers!  Really terrible design.  use a proper DATE type.  What happens when bad data gets into the table?

Comment: this works for me:  `select to_char(to_date(20161231,'YYYYMMDD'),'mm/dd/yyyy') from dual` so my guess is you have bad data that is not a valid month or day of month.

Comment: If you want to convert it to a date why are you converting it to a date and then to a char?

Comment: Are you storing single digit months and days with a leading zero? E.g. 20160105 ? And the year is always 4 digits?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check String of characters is a valid date or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45475877/check-string-of-characters-is-a-valid-date-or-not)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you to a `TO_DATE` on a number, it implicitly casts the number to `varchar2` and then passes that in to `TO_DATE`. As long as your number always had 8 digits (zero pads single digit months and days), and the date it represents actually exists on the calendar, it will work, though it is a bit sloppy to rely on implicit type conversions. It's better for clarity to be explicit about a `TO_CHAR` in a situation like this. But still, your code works.

So, you must have a bad numeric-date in your data. To find it, query:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT TO_DATE(tr.chemo_date DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR,'YYYYMMDD') converted_date,
               tr.*
          FROM mytable tr)
 WHERE converted_date IS NULL
   AND chemo_date IS NOT NULL
```

You can also create a function that traps exceptions to accomplish the same thing:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_safe_int_to_date(in_char IN integer,in_format IN varchar2)
  RETURN date
AS
BEGIN
  var_date := TO_DATE(in_char,in_format);

  RETURN var_date;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN NULL;
END;
```

/

```
 SELECT tr.*
   FROM mytable tr
  WHERE f_safe_int_to_date(tr.chemo_date,'YYYYMMDD') IS NULL
    AND tr.chemo_date IS NOT NULL
```

Once you identify the problem values you can probably figure out your data issue and resolve it.

Comment: Function to trap conversion is not good for performance. Although, I had to use such a function in versions before 12. It's best to use default on conversion error.

Comment: If you are using it diagnostically, it won't be part of your production code. Performance is not important in this context. Also with UDF pragma it's performance is not bad, though I agree, default on conversion error is pretty nifty and obviates this older method that may still be used on older versions. Other (non-date) type conversions that cause errors may still need a function-based approach to diagnose.

Comment: Thank you for this.  There were a few bad numbers in this field.

Answer (score 2):

If your column is a `NUMBER` then use `TO_DATE` to convert it to a date:

```sql
TO_DATE(TR.CHEMO_DATE, 'YYYYMMDD')
```

*Note: it is unclear why you are using `NUMBER(10)` when the format only has 8 digits.*

---

In Oracle, a `DATE` is a binary data-type that consists of 7 bytes representing century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second. It **ALWAYS** has those 7 components and it is **NEVER** stored in any particular format.

If you want to **display** a `DATE` in a specific format then either:

1. Change the settings of the client application you are using to access the database to allow it to format the date in a specific way.

   If you are using SQL*Plus or SQL Developer then you can use:

   ```sql
   ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='mm/dd/yyyy';
   ```

   Then use the query above.

   If you are using another client application then consult the documentation for that application.
2. Convert the `DATE` to a string using `TO_CHAR` (but then it will not be a `DATE`):

   ```sql
   TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(TR.CHEMO_DATE, 'YYYYMMDD'), 'mm/dd/yyyy') AS CHEM_DATE
   ```

   (Exactly as you did in the question)